# Cloud Foundry: CF-InvalidAuthToken"

Tags: cloud-foundry

I deployed Cloud Foundry using bosh, then used cf to login, but got the following errors:
[cf-login-error.log](https://github.com/leisore/DailyWork/blob/master/logs/cf-login.log)

My deployment file as following:
[cf-deployment.yml](https://github.com/leisore/DailyWork/blob/master/logs/cf-deployment.log)

I have spent more times to find where is wrong, but nothing is got.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is：

```
    jwt:  
      signing_key: '-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
        MIICXAIBAAKBgQDHFr+KICms+tuT1OXJwhCUmR2dKVy7psa8xzElSyzqx7oJyfJ1
        JZyOzToj9T5SfTIq396agbHJWVfYphNahvZ/7uMXqHxf+ZH9BL1gk9Y6kCnbM5R6   
        0gfwjyW1/dQPjOzn9N394zd2FJoFHwdq9Qs0wBugspULZVNRxq7veq/fzwIDAQAB
        AoGBAJ8dRTQFhIllbHx4GLbpTQsWXJ6w4hZvskJKCLM/o8R4n+0W45pQ1xEiYKdA
        Z/DRcnjltylRImBD8XuLL8iYOQSZXNMb1h3g5/UGbUXLmCgQLOUUlnYt34QOQm+0
        KvUqfMSFBbKMsYBAoQmNdTHBaz3dZa8ON9hh/f5TT8u0OWNRAkEA5opzsIXv+52J
        duc1VGyX3SwlxiE2dStW8wZqGiuLH142n6MKnkLU4ctNLiclw6BZePXFZYIK+AkE
        xQ+k16je5QJBAN0TIKMPWIbbHVr5rkdUqOyezlFFWYOwnMmw/BKa1d3zp54VP/P8
        +5aQ2d4sMoKEOfdWH7UqMe3FszfYFvSu5KMCQFMYeFaaEEP7Jn8rGzfQ5HQd44ek
        lQJqmq6CE2BXbY/i34FuvPcKU70HEEygY6Y9d8J3o6zQ0K9SYNu+pcXt4lkCQA3h
        jJQQe5uEGJTExqed7jllQ0khFJzLMx0K6tj0NeeIzAaGCQz13oo2sCdeGRHO4aDh
        HH6Qlq/6UOV5wP8+GAcCQFgRCcB+hrje8hfEEefHcFpyKH+5g1Eu1k0mLrxK2zd+
        4SlotYRHgPCEubokb2S1zfZDWIXW3HmggnGgM949TlY=  
        -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----'
      verification_key: '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
        MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDHFr+KICms+tuT1OXJwhCUmR2d
        KVy7psa8xzElSyzqx7oJyfJ1JZyOzToj9T5SfTIq396agbHJWVfYphNahvZ/7uMX
        qHxf+ZH9BL1gk9Y6kCnbM5R60gfwjyW1/dQPjOzn9N394zd2FJoFHwdq9Qs0wBug
        spULZVNRxq7veq/fzwIDAQAB
        -----END PUBLIC KEY-----'
```

Correct it as following:

```
    jwt:  
      signing_key: |
        -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
        MIICXAIBAAKBgQDHFr+KICms+tuT1OXJwhCUmR2dKVy7psa8xzElSyzqx7oJyfJ1
        JZyOzToj9T5SfTIq396agbHJWVfYphNahvZ/7uMXqHxf+ZH9BL1gk9Y6kCnbM5R6   
        0gfwjyW1/dQPjOzn9N394zd2FJoFHwdq9Qs0wBugspULZVNRxq7veq/fzwIDAQAB
        AoGBAJ8dRTQFhIllbHx4GLbpTQsWXJ6w4hZvskJKCLM/o8R4n+0W45pQ1xEiYKdA
        Z/DRcnjltylRImBD8XuLL8iYOQSZXNMb1h3g5/UGbUXLmCgQLOUUlnYt34QOQm+0
        KvUqfMSFBbKMsYBAoQmNdTHBaz3dZa8ON9hh/f5TT8u0OWNRAkEA5opzsIXv+52J
        duc1VGyX3SwlxiE2dStW8wZqGiuLH142n6MKnkLU4ctNLiclw6BZePXFZYIK+AkE
        xQ+k16je5QJBAN0TIKMPWIbbHVr5rkdUqOyezlFFWYOwnMmw/BKa1d3zp54VP/P8
        +5aQ2d4sMoKEOfdWH7UqMe3FszfYFvSu5KMCQFMYeFaaEEP7Jn8rGzfQ5HQd44ek
        lQJqmq6CE2BXbY/i34FuvPcKU70HEEygY6Y9d8J3o6zQ0K9SYNu+pcXt4lkCQA3h
        jJQQe5uEGJTExqed7jllQ0khFJzLMx0K6tj0NeeIzAaGCQz13oo2sCdeGRHO4aDh
        HH6Qlq/6UOV5wP8+GAcCQFgRCcB+hrje8hfEEefHcFpyKH+5g1Eu1k0mLrxK2zd+
        4SlotYRHgPCEubokb2S1zfZDWIXW3HmggnGgM949TlY=  
        -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
      verification_key: |
        -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
        MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDHFr+KICms+tuT1OXJwhCUmR2d
        KVy7psa8xzElSyzqx7oJyfJ1JZyOzToj9T5SfTIq396agbHJWVfYphNahvZ/7uMX
        qHxf+ZH9BL1gk9Y6kCnbM5R60gfwjyW1/dQPjOzn9N394zd2FJoFHwdq9Qs0wBug
        spULZVNRxq7veq/fzwIDAQAB
        -----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Then it's OK, and I can do login successfully!